# Why doesn't the ASP.Net WebForms RegularExpressionValidator accept lower case for validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, webforms

For an ASP.Net WebForms page, I want to match only K, L, M, N and P in both upper and lower case as the first character of an input mask (L0L 0L0).

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="<%#ResourceApplicantIntakeCustomerInformation.msgInvalidPostalCode%>" ControlToValidate="txtMailingZip" ForeColor="red" Enabled="true" 
                ValidationExpression="^[KLMNPklmnp][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I also tried changing the order to `klmnpKLMNP`, same issue.

The problem is that I always have to use capital letters.  I also tried a css
`text-transform: uppercase;`, but same issue.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that your lower case letters `klmnp` are causing validation error? What if you try `text-tranform: none`?

Comment: If you remove the lowercase letters from the first character class - `"^[KLMNP][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$"` - will it work as expected?

Comment: Or vice versa: `^[KLMNPklmnp][0-9][A-Za-z] ?[0-9][A-Za-z][0-9]$`?

Comment: First I tried with `KLMNP` and had text `text-transform: uppercase;`.  If I had caps lock off, (typing lower-case but appeared as upper-case) validation failed.  So I added lower case `klmnp`, still wasn't passing, so I removed the `text-transform` - still not working.